# How to write code for compare the value in textbox and column in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to write code to compare the value for Serial number and equipment id with the column in SQL Server. If the value that user search have been deleted or remove I want to show " no record found".

My problem here is I do not know how to write the code for if statement.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=5CG50749V3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM [Equipment] WHERE SerialNumber='" + SerialNumber.Text + "' or EquipmentID ='" + EquipmentID.Text + "'", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    SerialNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
    EquipmentID.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will show a popup if the record is not found

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=5CG50749V3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM [Equipment] WHERE SerialNumber='" + SerialNumber.Text + "' or EquipmentID ='" + EquipmentID.Text + "'", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

       if (dt.Rows.Count != 0) // this will check weather any records are returned
           {
               // If record is found
              SerialNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
              EquipmentID.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
           }
        else //if no record is found it will display alert
             {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('no record found');", true);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rows.count of the datatable (dt)

```
If (dt.rows.count == 0)
{
  ' no rows returned, notify user
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to set a breakpoint and look at what's going on with the values. I see some issues in your query where you have the possibility of returning more than one row and since you statically only look at row 0 is might return unwanted results. But if none of these answers are working, we're either misunderstanding you or you are asking for something different than what you're really needing.

Answer (score 0):

give it a try

```
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count >0)
{
//Then your logic
}
else
{
//popup script
}
```

Comment: The problem is the user have to fill the one of the text box which is serialnumber or equipment id. if dt = null the it will jump to else statement. how to make sure it can accept either serial number or equipment id can have the value.@Saeed